# MongoDB unable to eliminate certain fields from mongodb query result

Tags: mongodb

I have got records in my collection as shown below

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("53722c39e4b04a53021cf3c6"), 
 "symbol" : "AIA", 
 "tbq" : 1356, 
 "tsq" : 0, 
 "tquan" : 6831336, 
 "tvol" : 17331.78, 
 "bquantity" : 1356, 
 "squantity" : 0 
}

{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("53722c38e4b04a53021cf3c1"), 
 "symbol" : "SAA", 
 "tbq" : 0, 
 "tsq" : 9200, 
 "tquan" : 6036143, 
 "tvol" : 50207.43, 
 "bquantity" : 0, 
 "squantity" : 9200 
}
```

I am displaying the results in the ascending order of bquantity, and also at the same time  I want to display only certain columns in the result (symbol, bquantity, squantity) and ignore the rest.

I tried with the below query, but still its displaying all the fields .

Please tell me how can i eliminate those fields from the result ?

```
db.stock.find().sort(
                     {"bquantity":-1}, 
                     { 
                       symbol: 1, 
                       bquantity: 1, 
                       squantity:1 ,
                       _id:0,
                       tbq:0,
                       tsq:0,
                       tquan:0,
                       tvol:0
                      } 
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field filter is a parameter to the `find` function, not to the sort function, i.e.:

```
db.stock.find({}, { _id:0,tbq:0, tsq:0,tquan:0,tvol:0}).sort({"bquantity":-1})
```

The empty hash used as first parameter to `find` is required as an 'empty query' which matches all documents in `stock`.

Comment: Thansk , but when i trid this , i am getting this exception error: {
        "$err" : "You cannot currently mix including and excluding fields. Contact us if this is an issue.",
        "code" : 10053
}

Comment: @Kiran That error explains it all, you can't mix 0s and 1s in the field filter, so you either have to explicitly tell it which to show or tell it which to hide, not both. However the _id column is an exception, it can be hidden even if you are specifying columns to show.

Comment: Yeah, right.. Sorry, fixed the answer. Whether to only include or only exclude fields depends on the number of fields and whether you need to get rid of `_id` or not.